# Getting rid of environment specific configuration in jars and wars

Tags: properties, web-deployment

This is a common issue that I've found at various companies:

We produce jars, wars, and ears that contain client specific configuration inside the artifact. Deployment directions are usually:

```
* Unzip the war/jar/ear
* Go to directory that contains the configuration properties.
* Rename config-prod3.properties to config.properties (or even worse, edit the config.properties file directly)
* Remove the rest of the configuration properties
* archive the deployable back up
* Now, copy it to its deployment location.
```

As the CM, my job is to oversee builds and deployments. unzipping and rezipping these deployment containers strikes me as just bad. It just makes deployments more difficult and time consuming.

At one company, I setup our build system to build *customized jars/wars* for each environment. Deployment was simple, but I wasn't thrilled with this because the number of these archives increases with the number of environments. Plus, I am not deploying the same jar from my dev to QA to UAT to the Production environment. Yes, the jars were built all at the same time, and are identical except for these properties files, but it makes me queasy that a jar we are deploying on production never had been tested directly in our UAT or QA environment.

At our current company, I've written automated deployment scripts that manually unzip and rezip these archive files and munge the properties files in them. These scripts are expensive to maintain, and they are my responsibility which means when the developer makes some change (like add another property file), I don't get notified until the deployment fails.

I'm not a Java developer, so I don't know the ***correct*** way to handle this. My initial inclination would be to put everything into a database. A single *properties* file will simply tell the app where to find the database. All values (based upon the environment or hostname) will be pulled from the database. However, developers tell me this will require extensive rewriting of the applications and would be too difficult to implement. (My cynical mind translates this as *You want us to fix a problem that doesn't directly affect me? No way!*).

We use Tomcat and JBoss, and I was wondering if these properties files could be placed elsewhere on the server, and the JBoss or Tomcat configuration could track them down. (For example, something like a `$CLASSPATH`). How much work would developers have to do for this type of change? Just make sure they don't use absolute paths when reading from properties files? Or, is this too difficult to do? (Again, developers tell me this is also too complex to implement.)

What would be the easiest way to remove system specific properties files from deployable artifacts? What do you do at your company to handle this issue?

My issue isn't to pawn off *my job* onto another group. It's to make deployments go smoother and faster. This would allow us to deploy more in our testing environment, and would be less error prone. I've been documenting deployment issues, and how it affects our customers, and how many man-hours it takes to fix. I can make the argument that the current system is broken. I just don't have enough knowledge to recommend some sort of fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An externalized store of config is the right idea. Need not be the database though. For example, here is a good article advocating the use of environment variable for this purpose:

http://12factor.net/config

Another (big iron) option is to use something like Apache Zookeeper

http://zookeeper.apache.org/

Comment: I'm not found of environment variables. They simply aren't stable. Besides, what do you do when you have two or more apps running in the same environment? My main problem is moving from what we now which is a big pain for me and IT to something that makes our job easier, but without massive programming change. Zookeeper is a good way to go, but that involves setting up Zookeeper and getting our programs setup to use it.

Comment: They are as stable as the process that's using them. many apps, many processes.

Comment: I'm doing some preliminary ground work with Zookeeper. We won't replace all properties files right now -- just the stuff that changes from environment to environment. I'm looking into writing a class that can replace the Properties class. This way, the developer can simply replace the class, but the methods remain the same, so there's less programming changes. The issue is now how we maintain the Zoo. It was easy with properties files. When a program changes, the properties files change too. Now, we have to time changes in Zookeeper with releases. We'll work something out.